# How to setup a Java agent in a Spring boot app deployed in PCF cloud

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, javaagents

I have a Spring boot app deployed into PCF cloud. I need to setup a Java agent on it. How do I give the JVM options? How to include the agent jar in the deployed jar file? I use Maven to build.

Comment: solution Found ? @Ben.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the JVM options as env settings in the application manifest file.

This link provides details on manifest options
 - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

And here's an article that has tips for java developers. It has examples on setting memory and other settings for java app.
 - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

To run a spring boot app with a javagent use following jvm option.

```
-javaagent:<name-of-the-jar>
```

Use following plugin in your maven project to copy agent jar file on compile.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="${basedir}/src/path-to-jar" tofile="${basedir}/target/jar-file"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```